# Internal dependencies class qualified name conflict

Tags: java, gradle

There are two dependency libraries in my Gradle project:

- OLD: full util lib
- NEW: only db lib (fixed lib)

which both holds same db connection classes including package eg.: *net.mycompany.common.dbsq.DBConnector()*.

What I need is to ensure use of db connection classes from NEW, but keeping OLD (can be without db classes) as dependency due to rest of needed utils, that are not available in NEW.

Is there possibility to exclude/include just particular classes or packages of dependency? Or ensure 'overriding' of same named classes? Unfortunately it is not question of transitive dependency, but name conflicting db connection classes are in both. Also I cant have any impact on content of dependencies.

With specifying both as compile dependencies, IDE (Idea) uses classes from NEW, but running .war in weblogic server uses db connection classes from OLD.

Any ideas? I can give more specific description, but this is quite general question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are including two libraries, you are including them full.

I can only think of two approaches:

1. remove old dependency and check which are the new libraries that include the classes you depend on. usually, when a project replaces packaging based on one full jar by packaging based on more fine grined ones, you can have full set of classes by just adding all fine-grined libraries. If you tell us which is your library it will be easier to answer with more specific stuff.
2. take old library and repackage it with only your needed classes. Discouraged and easy to lead to issues.

Best option is the 1.

Comment: Thank you, it is internal few years old lib which is not maintained any more, so I cant expect any updates or continuation like more grined version (separate db part in my case). I will try take .jar of OLD, and remove db classes package.

Comment: Nevertheless this is far away from ideal solution, download OLD .jar, remove needed package and configure it as file dependency solved my problem.